# Getting access to a variable from an Apex class into a Visual force page that has standard Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardcontroller

How can I use the variable value from apex class into a visualforce page which has a standard controller?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the class as an extension. `<apex:page extension="your_class"></apex:page>`

Comment: Which class I have to use as extension? 
The class from where I want to access variable value ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access controller variable in javascript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20668/access-controller-variable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extensions` attribute of `<apex:page>` component for refer to any extensions you need. Refer below simple example from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) and understand how to bind the extension with the page and specially the constructor of the extension.

Extension :

```
public class myControllerExtension {

    private final Account acct;

    // The extension constructor initializes the private member
    // variable acct by using the getRecord method from the standard
    // controller.
    public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        return 'Hello ' + acct.name + ' (' + acct.id + ')';
    }
}
```

Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="myControllerExtension">
    {!greeting} <p/>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/> <p/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You can see the variable `greeting` is coming from the method `getGreeting()` (getter of `greeting` in other words) in the controller. Likewise you can declare variables in your extension class and bind them in the page as you do with a controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page standardController="object__c" extensions="MyExtension">
  ...
  <apex:outputText value="{!name}"/>
</apex:page>
```

In your MyExtension

```
public class MyExtension {

   public String name {get; set;}
   private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

   public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
       this.stdController = stdController;
       getMyName();
   }

   private void getMyName() {
      name = 'Hello World';
   }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If name is changed in a method other than Constructor, can we use it in same way as you did>

Comment: Yes, but the method needs to be invoked by the constructor or a button click.

Comment: This is not working for me. :( Its is showing me error, "Unknown constructor 'QuandlStockDetailsCntl.QuandlStockDetailsCntl(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'

Comment: You constructor name is incorrect, it should be QuandlStockDetailsCntl(ApexPages.StandardController controller), assuming QuandlStockDetailsCntl is the name of the extension class.

Comment: Yes QuandlStockDetailsCntl is name of extension class but I only include this and got error.

Answer (score 0):

Awais,

If u want to use the value from controller to page then in that case u can just define the variable as an getter and setter method and use Apexpages.standardcontroller Variable_name and use the instance of this to use the functionality of standard object. For further help u can go through link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_methods.htm

in case if u want to use value from the page to the controller then u can use .

<------------Controller---------->

```
public with sharing class Details{


public list<Account>myList{get;set;}
public list<Contact>myList1{get;set;}
Apexpages.standardcontroller controller;    
    public Details(Apexpages.standardcontroller con){

        controller = con;
        myList=new list<Account>();
        myList=[select id,Name,AccountNumber,Phone,Website from Account];
        String d = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        //myList1 = new list<contact>();
        myList1= [select id,Name,MobilePhone,Email,Birthdate from Contact where accountId= :d];

        }

    Public PageReference mycontactdetails(){
        /*if( ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')!= null)
        myList1= [select id,Name,MobilePhone,Email,Birthdate from Contact where accountId= :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        System.debug(myList1);
        */return null;

    }
```

}
<--------------Page------------>

```
<apex:Form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myList}" var="v" >
            <apex:column value="{!v.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!v.AccountNumber}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!v.Phone}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!v.Website}"/>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!mycontactdetails}" reRender="contactdetails" value="{!v.Name}"/>
            <apex:param name="id" value="{!v.id}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:Form>
```

```
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myList1}" var="c" id="myList1">
                <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.MobilePhone}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.Email}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.Birthdate}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>
         </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Thanks.

Comment: No, I just want to get value from an apex class in a visualforce page. Visualforce page has standard controller but I need value from a different apex class. Its something like hierarchy,
1- I have a visualforce pahe with standard controller, from where I click on a button, which opens a popup window that shows me a vf page with a custom controller. here from this page, I am making a page-reference to another page which also has a custom controller. Now this custom class has the variable that I need in 1st vf page. 
I think my question/scenario is clear to you?